# R Shiny Reactive input file with conditions

Tags: r, file-io, shiny, reactive

I am using R shiny to build a dashboard which takes in two speadsheets and compare them to give me some results. When I did this for one pattern, it works just fine. But when I am trying to add two different types of comparison based on an input parameter, it is not passing through. Here is what I was doing in the server.R originally (and which works),

```
report1 <- eventReactive(input$Report1, {
read.csv(input$Report1$datapath)

report2 <- eventReactive(input$Report2, {
read.csv(input$Report2$datapath)
```

Where Report1 and Report2 are the input files coming from ui.R. What I want is to add a parameter which will decide how to handle the input file. Say the two handling methods are called "Method1" and "Method2". I cannot use the same method to call both types, since the second set of files is of .crm format, which is a ";" separated file, something R is not directly recognizing. 
To be clear, the following code works fine for .crm file in a non server run.

```
File <- read.csv(file, sep = ";", header = TRUE)
```

So what I want to do is

```
handlingMethod <- reactive(input$Method)

if (handlingMethod() == "Method1"){

    report1 <- eventReactive(input$Report1, {
    read.csv(input$Report1$datapath)})

    report2 <- eventReactive(input$Report2, {
    read.csv(input$Report2$datapath)})

} else if (handlingMethod() == "Method2"){

    report1 <- eventReactive(input$Report1, {
    read.csv(input$Report1$datapath,sep = ";", header = TRUE)})

    report2 <- eventReactive(input$Report2, {
    read.csv(input$Report2$datapath, sep = ";", header = TRUE)})
} else {}
```

But this gives me the error "You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer." I thought I had understood that problem and resolved it, but apparently not. Then I put the whole thing within a reactive expression as follows,

```
reactive({if (handlingMethod() == "Method1"){

            report1 <- eventReactive(input$Report1, {
            read.csv(input$Report1$datapath)})

            report2 <- eventReactive(input$Report2, {
            read.csv(input$Report2$datapath)})

        } else if (handlingMethod() == "Method2"){

            report1 <- eventReactive(input$Report1, {
            read.csv(input$Report1$datapath,sep = ";", header = TRUE)})

            report2 <- eventReactive(input$Report2, {
            read.csv(input$Report2$datapath, sep = ";", header = TRUE)})
        } else {}})
```

Which makes the shiny app run, but then show me the message,"Error in report1: could not find function "report1""

Has anyone seen this sort of error before? If so, I should be grateful if you tell me what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the `if...else...` into the `eventReactive`. Also the line `handlingMethod <- reactive(input$Method)` seems unnecessary as you can just use `input$Method` directly instead of copying it to `handlingMethod()`. See below:

```
report1 <- eventReactive(input$Report1, {
    if (input$Method == "Method1"){
        read.csv(input$Report1$datapath)
    } else if (input$Method == "Method2"){
        read.csv(input$Report1$datapath,sep = ";", header = TRUE)
    } else{}
})

report2 <- eventReactive(input$Report2, {
    if (input$Method == "Method1"){
        read.csv(input$Report2$datapath)
    } else if (input$Method == "Method2"){
        read.csv(input$Report2$datapath, sep = ";", header = TRUE)
    } else{}
})
```

I don't think the `else{}` is necessary but not a big deal.

Comment: It works! I just put the 'else' there because I was anticipating more conditions to join the two in the future:-). As for the assignment of inputs to a variable, it seemed like the neater thing to do. Thank you very much for the help, @Eli_Berkow